# How to set up on click listener on the contact list retrieved from phone

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have retrieved the contacts from my phone into a listview using cursor and simplecursorAdaptor .
Now i want  to set an onClickListener on the contact llist that i have retrieved ,that will just toast the contact info (like contact name ,contact no)

I have tried to set a listener on the contact list , but failed every time

please help, 
This is my code

```
    ListView contact_list;
    contact_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_contacts);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from= {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

    int[] to= {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor,from,to);
    contact_list.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    contact_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

XML Code -:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".ContactsActivity">

       <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list_contacts"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The click listener is set on the ListView so:

```
contact_list.setOnItemClickListener((list, view, pos) -> {
     Cursor item = list.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
     // you have the item clicked and do something
};
```